# How can I get row colors to change in standard grid based on data criteria

Tags: acumatica

I have a situation where I want a grid row to be a specific color, based on what one of the fields in that row is set to.

I've looked at this case:

[How can we set color for particular column filed value conditionally in Acumatica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61922470/how-can-we-set-color-for-particular-column-filed-value-conditionally-in-acumatic/61936740#61936740)

Also here:

http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/using-colors-in-acumatica.html

And it works - to a point.  Unfortunately, it only changes the color when you click on one of the rows, not when the screen loads or when the field is updated and the save is clicked.  Does the event "grid_RowDataBound" not fire when the page is refreshed or a save even happens?

Bottom line:  How can I get this to set the row color when the screen is refreshed or when the field is updated / screen saved?

If a user has to click on one of the rows for this functionality to occur, it's not of much use.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

A better place to put the javascript method is under the PXDataSource aspx control:

```
<px:PXDataSource>
    <ClientEvents Initialize="HighlightLines" CommandPerformed="HighlightLines"/>
</px:PXDataSource>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function HighlightLines ()
        {
            if(px_all && px_all["ctl00_phG_grid <=the html ID of the grid"] && px_all["ctl00_phG_grid"].rows)
            {
                let lines = px_all["ctl00_phG_grid"].rows.items;
                for(let i=0;i<lines.length;i++)
                {
                    let currentLine=lines[i];
                    if(currentLine.getCell("DAC__Field").getValue() == 'SomeValue')
                    {
                        currentLine.style = 'background-color: green';
                        currentLine.repaint();
                    }
                    else if (currentLine.getCell("DAC__Field").getValue() == 'SomeOtherValue')
                    {
                        currentLine.style = 'background-color: yellow';
                        currentLine.repaint();
                    }
                    else if (currentLine.getCell("NGSampleTest__Test").getValue() == 'PGTAND')
                    {
                        currentLine.style = 'background-color: red';
                        currentLine.repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: But it's not a Javascript method.  It's a C# codebehind page method.  Do you have a Javascript event example that would achieve the same row coloring?

Comment: Edited the original post

Comment: Beauty - thanks much, Kyle!  ;D